# Sorting with a predefined list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort this dataframe:

```
 Age  grade name
 21.0   6   John 
 21.0   6   Paul
 22.8   4   Jake
```

With the help of a list of names:

```
Paul, Jake, John
```

What is the most simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data generation:

```
txt <- 
"Age  grade name
21.0   6   John 
21.0   6   Paul
22.8   4   Jake "
df <- read.table(text=txt, header=T)
```

In order to support custom sorting you can convert column to factor with specified levels:

```
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels=c("Paul", "Jake", "John"))
```

Now ordering `df[order(df$name),]` gives:

```
   Age grade name
2 21.0     6 Paul
3 22.8     4 Jake
1 21.0     6 John
```

Comment: Should add a note to make it clear that `order` acts on the numerical order of the factors, not their alpha sorting order.